# How do I add another condition on my python code?

Tags: python

This python program would determine a superhero name based on the user input. My problem is that the code itself works fine but there's a condition that I wanted to add. I wanted to add a condition where if the user enters "B" or "b", in the first question (which is the power), it would skip the second question (which is the year) and instead, would jump to a new set of questions where it would ask:

"how many years have you had your Cold superpowers for?"

and

"how many years have you had your Heat superpowers for?"

And at the end, the superhero name is determined by which of these two are the dominant. (longer year is the dominant)

The solution that I could think of is to make another module and call for that module for when the user inputs "B" or "b" in module A.

```
#module A
def get_power(question):
  power = input(question)
  if (power == "H" or power == "h"):
    power = "Fire"
  elif (power == "C" or power == "c"):
      power = "Ice"
  else:
    print("Invalid input... Please enter H for heat, C for cold and B for both")
    power = get_power("Does your powers work with heat, cold or both?: ")
  return power

#module B
def get_year(question):
  year = int(input(question)) 
  if (year % 2 == 0 and year <= 100):
    year = "Lightning"
  elif (year % 2 != 0 and year <= 100):
    year = "Shadow"
  else:
    print("Invalid input... Please enter a year between 1 and 100 only")
    year = get_year("How many years have you had your superpowers for?: ")
  return year 
  
#Main
power = get_power("Does your powers work with heat, cold or both?: ")
year = get_year("How many years have you had your superpowers for?: ")
print("Congratulations! Your superhero name is", power, year)
```

Comment: Just add it how you added the elif?

Comment: Do I just add `elif (power == "B" or power == "b"):` under `power = "Ice"` @12944qwerty

Comment: Yes. How is this confusing? You already have done this for the ice power?

Comment: And what would the power be equal to if the user inputs "B" or "b"?

Comment: That is your choice? How is that ours? This is your question meaning you have control over all the details. I'd assume it is both powers though since "b" is the keyword for "both" in your post.

Comment: Small hint: use `power = input(question).lower()` so you don't have to compare twice for each letter.

Comment: You should use the `question` argument as the prompt when you ask the question again at the bottom of each function. Also, don't use recursion as a substitute for looping, this isn't Scheme.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I just noticed the the `question` argument. I've changed it thank you. And also, what does recursion mean? Sorry I'm just learning.

Comment: Recursion means a function calling itself. `get_power()` calls `get_power()` at the end if the input doesn't validate.